# IF NOT EXISTS - Mariadb Syntax

Tags: sql, mariadb, exists

i tried to either insert a new row or update an existing one if it is already included.

I figured i could try it with indices but to be honest i am not sure how to do this hence i tried to do it with an IF statement.
Unfortunatly this isn't working either because it says i have a problem with my Syntax. I am using MariaDB.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM valuation 
               WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' AND depot_id =1 
                 AND src_id =2 AND valuation_date ='2009-09-09')
INSERT INTO valuation (ticker,depot_id,src_id,valuation_date,value) 
VALUES ('BK001EUR',1,2,'2009-09-09',14999260.46) 
ELSE 
UPDATE valuation 
SET value =14999260.46 
WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' AND depot_id =1 
  AND src_id =2 AND valuation_date ='2009-09-09');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
-- if exists then it will update
UPDATE valuation 
SET value =14999260.46 
WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' 
  AND depot_id =1 AND src_id =2 AND valuation_date ='2009-09-09';

-- if not exist then insert
INSERT INTO valuation (ticker,depot_id,src_id,valuation_date,value)
SELECT 'BK001EUR',1,2,'2009-09-09',14999260.46
-- FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM valuation 
                   WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' 
                     AND depot_id =1 
                     AND src_id =2 AND valuation_date ='2009-09-09');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a2b13d3011e1272a99ecabca7ceaed93)**

Or better way [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/):

```
INSERT INTO valuation (ticker,depot_id,src_id,valuation_date,value) 
VALUES ('BK001EUR',1,2,'2009-09-09',14999260.46)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value =14999260.46;
```

Comment: i tried "on duplicate key update" but unfortunatly it only relates to the primary key which is the ticker and i do not know how to relate it to an index based on all 4 columns.

Comment: `UPDATE valuation SET value =14999260.46 WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' AND src_id =2 AND depot_id = 1 AND valuation_date ='2009-09-09');

INSERT INTO valuation (ticker,depot_id,src_id,valuation_date,value) SELECT 'BK001EUR',1,2,'2009-09-09',14999260.46 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM valuation WHERE ticker = 'BK001EUR' AND depot_id = 1 AND src_id = 2 AND valuation_date = '2009-09-09');
`

Comment: You forgot to add `FROM DUAL` before your where not exists line.

Comment: @Kevin The dual is not mandatory: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a2b13d3011e1272a99ecabca7ceaed93) starting from MariaDB 10.4, but I upated my answer for completness

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is using `insert ... on duplicate key update`.  I would write the query as:

```
INSERT INTO valuation (ticker, depot_id, src_id, valuation_date, value) 
  VALUES ('BK001EUR', 1, 2, '2009-09-09', 14999260.46) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

(Note the use of `VALUES()` so you don't have to repeat the input.)

For this to work, you need a *unique* index on the keys you care about:

```
create unique index unq_valuation_4 on valuation(ticker, depot_id, src_id, valuation_date);
```

The duplicate key does not need to be the primary key index.
It can be any unique index.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar INSERT-statement, which should not insert the data, if a record with the same values exists. My statement didn't work until I added 'FROM DUAL':

```
INSERT INTO measurement
    (sensorid, parameterid, measuredatetime, measure)
    SELECT sensoridIn,parameteridIn,measuredatetimeIn,measureIn
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM measurement
          WHERE sensorid = sensorId
          AND measuredatetime = measuredatetimeIn
          AND measure = measureIn
          AND parameterid = parameteridIn);
```

For more info see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dual/ and [How can I do 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-can-i-do-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)